# Apportable wrong choosing the OpenGL ES

Tags: android, ios, apportable

I use apportable to convert my iphone app to android but i wrongly configure it with opengl ES 2. However can I reset it? I want to rebuild the apk again. Please let me know how to fix it thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check file ***configuration.json*** in your application ***xxxx.approj*** directory

Find **"FEATURES": ["opengles2", ... ]**

Remove **"opengles2"** might do the trick for you

See this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/apportable-discuss/opengles1/apportable-discuss/JW_03dLXshg/qZ-ICAPD3nYJ) for reference.